# Multiple rewriterule in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Multiple rewriterule in .htaccess 
not working

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^f.aspx f.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^icons.aspx icons.php [L]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: the line num 1 is working but the line number 2 or 3 ... not work

Comment: where is the line 3? Your code has only 2 rules

Comment: What is the full URL you are trying to access? `^` means that the path must start like that.

Comment: i don't understand ?. my problem is clear the line 1 is worked in all form f.aspx?f=1 or f.aspx?t=1 ..etc but the line 2 isn't working

Comment: "Not working" is not very helpful to us. Please explain *exactly* what happens when you try to access `icons.aspx`. What do you see? What loads?

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL icons.aspx was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Okay, now are you 100% sure that `icons.php` exists in the same directory as `f.php`? Check to make sure it is not `icon.php` (without the `s`). And what happens if you remove the rule for `icons.aspx` and change the first rule to `RewriteRule ^(f|icons).aspx$ /$1.php [L]`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a `$` after `.aspx`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^f.aspx$ f.php [L]
RewriteRule ^icons.aspx$ icons.php [L]
```

Comment: the line num 1 is working but the line number 2 or 3 ... not work

Comment: could you provide more explanation about what is working and what is not working?